# How to restrict connections to glassfish?

Tags: glassfish-3, ip-restrictions

I'm running a web application on a glassfish 3 server. The application should not be accessible for anyone. Instead I want to limit access to a handful static IP addresses. To block all communication via a firewall is not an option, since the server hosts other web services too.

Given this background, my question would be:
How can I tell glassfish to only respond to requests from given number of IP addresses?

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

IP based security is not very robust and... secure (think network topology changes, IP spoofing) but it should be possible to:

- create a virtual server
- configure the application to be available on that virtual server only
- define [allowRemoteHost](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1753/auto337/index.html)/[denyRemoteHost](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1753/auto337/index.html) properties at the virtual server level

A better alternative would be to move to certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a filter that returns 404 or whatever for invalid IPs. Note that IPs can be spoofed.